# Stay on the Application When i click adView android

Tags: android, admob, adview

I Implemented a adview into my application if i click on that adview. the ad should be called but should not show in front. our Application has to be shown in front..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a thread to load. In your case you can use AsyncTask. I have pasted below the tutorial whch will help you to implement:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

As you may be knowing that android application starts in UI thread (main thread). If you want to do any work in parallel, you can do it in a thread and post the result back to UI thread. Android has given support to threading using ASYNCTASK. Using this implementing thread logic is very easy. You can follow tutorail to understand in detail. Another helpful link:

[AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

Comment: Susil Thanks.. But i Tried all the way what u have told.. I couldnt found what i expect...